# Initializing parameter of a class method with value during declaration C++

Tags: c++, class, methods

I am working on another persons C++ code and don't understand why they did something.

They have a notification class that has a public method called check which takes in the time as a parameter

```
void check(unsigned long time = 1);
```

Every time the method is called in the code a current time is passed to it.

```
notification1.check(currentTime);
```

My question is why did they give the parameter a value when they defined the method? Why not just say,

```
void check(unsigned long time);
```

Comment: I would say it is better style to not have default parameter if parameter is always provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because if no argument if provided in function call, default argument value will be used for `time` which is `1` in this case. This is called [Default Argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_argument)

If you call `check` function and provide no argument, default value of `1` will be assigned to `time` by the compiler. If you pass an argument while calling `check` function, that passed value will override the default value of `time`.

When a function has a default argument passed in to it, you are not required to pass an argument while calling that function and you can specify as many default arguments as you want.

Comment: I thought it might be that. Is this just done for safety ? They have never called the function without giving it a time so I just couldn't see the point in having it there.

Comment: it is used to ensure that if no arguments is passed in function call by the user, the default value is used by the program

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the implementation of check function?

since there is default argument specified in function declaration, you can call it without arguments as well. (ex: notification1.check() )  you should explore what is the behaviour of the check(...) function in each of following scenarios

- Function call WITH an argument? (i.e. notification1.check(currentTime))?
- Function call WITHOUT argument? (i.e. notification1.check())?

As a best practice of coding, these behaviours has to be documented with the member function declaration. if it is not the case, you'll have to explore the implementation.

Comment: Hi Curiosity, I do indeed have access and have already done what you suggested. Running the method with a 1 made no sense and did not work at all, this is what prompted me to ask my question. I thought it was something I didn't understand but it looks like it was just an oversight on the developers part.

Comment: agreed, having default argument might had some intention in developer's original design, But subsequently, it has become no meaningful at all. might forgot to remove it from declaration as time is passed by.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default argument. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments explains all you ever wanted to know about this C++ feature.

> My question is why did they give the parameter a value when they defined the method?

If the default argument is not used *anywhere*, i.e. if the function is always called with a non-default argument, then chances are it was a wrong design decision. Perhaps they thought the default argument was useful when they originally designed the code, but it now turned out that there is no useful default value. Or perhaps they think that the default argument may still be useful in the future.

As a matter of fact, `1` *is* a questionable value for an `unsigned long time` parameter, which looks a lot like a value representing [milliseconds since January 1st 1970](https://currentmillis.com/). Why not `0`?

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the reply. I think you might be right regarding it being old code that is of no use now. And the value 1 made no sense, that's what prompted me to ask the question. The time that is passed to the check function is usually a unixtime or a machine time (time since the machine has been on). If I put a 1 in place of either the function would not operate correctly at all so I suspect that it is just a bad decision on the other engineers part.